# Java Annotation how to get current ElemenType of specific annotation

Tags: java, annotations

My annotation:

```java
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ObjectName {
    String name() default "";
    String field() default "";
}
```

Some class with my annotation

```java
@ObjectName("a_")
public class A {
    
    @ObjectName("field_")
    String filed;
}
```

Problem - when i get all my "ObjectName" annotations from class above, how can i get annotation's ElementType value (field, class or method type)?
So i want something like this

```java
public void process(Class<?> clazz) {
    Annotation[] annotations = clazz.getAnnotations();
    for (Annotation anno : annotations) {
       if (anno instanceof ObjectName) {
          ObjectName annObjName = (ObjectName) anno;
          Target target = anno.getAnnotation(Target.class);
          if (target.getType().equals(ElementType.TYPE)
              doThat(annObjName.name());
          else if (target.getType().equals(ElementType.FIELD)
              doThis(annObjName.field());
       }
    }
}
```

1. Can i even do this?
2. How can i do this or how can i find out if this annotation declared on filed or class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

All you can do is look at where you call `getAnnotations()`, because you seem to incorrectly believe that `clazz.getAnnotations()` will return all annotations on everything in the class.  That is false.  When you call `clazz.getAnnotations()`, you will only get the annotations directly on the class.  To get annotations on fields, you must call `clazz.getFields()`, and then call `getAnnotations()` on the `Field` elements.  So there's no risk of getting them mixed up as long as you keep those straight.

Comment: Ok, thx. Then there is only one option to get all class annotations and field annotations and compare if its instance of ObjectName